# Rotate object around a circle within the specified time

Tags: javascript, math, rotation

I have a function which rotates an object around a circle. I set the time to go around the circle at 10,000 milliseconds.

But the object does not rotate in that length of time, it seems to be a lot faster. And am unsure how to correct for this.

My update function which sets the x,y position of the object looks like this:

```
var obj             = [];

    var t           = {};
    var angle       = Math.random()*Math.PI*2; //start angle
        t.radius    = 200;
        t.x         = Math.cos(angle)*t.radius; //start position x
        t.y         = Math.sin(angle)*t.radius; //start position y
        t.circumference= t.radius * 2 * Math.PI;//circumference
        t.duration  = 10000; //10 seconds per rotation
        t.start     = Date.now();


obj.push(t);

function update(){
    var delta,vector,angle;
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        delta       = Date.now() - obj[i].start;
        obj.start   = Date.now();
        vector      = obj[i].circumference / obj[i].duration;
        angle       = vector * delta;
        obj[i].x    = obj[i].radius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180);
        obj[i].y    = obj[i].radius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI/180);                                
    }
}

function draw(){
    update();

    // draw my object etc

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

I also have the animation running here set to 10,000 milliseconds, yet it rotates far quicker than that: http://jsfiddle.net/7geez8bf/

So, i am wondering how can correct this to rotate around at the length of time i declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `angle` is actually still a portion of circumference (length / time * time), not an angle.

If you normalize it with your radius, it then becomes an angle in radian, so you no longer need the degree-to-radian conversion in the Math.cos and Math.sin.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7geez8bf/2/

Note that you could easily factorize your code by directly remembering the vector value (to be a portion of angle in radian per ms). It then becomes a rotational speed, in radian per ms: `t.rotSpeed = 2 * Math.PI / t.duration);`

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/7geez8bf/3/

Answer (score 1):

There are various inconsistencies in your code. E.g. you mix radians and degrees. The angular position should not depend on the circumfence (because you set the duration of one complete circle instead of a velocity). Here's the updated code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    var delta               = Date.now() - obj[i].start;
    obj[i].start            = Date.now();
    obj[i].angle            += 2 * Math.PI * delta / obj[i].duration;
    obj[i].x                = obj[i].radius * Math.cos(obj[i].angle);
    obj[i].y                = obj[i].radius * Math.sin(obj[i].angle);                               
}
```